# Beginner Oracle SQL Count Function Multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, function, count

I am going through a practice worksheet with questions and expected outputs. The last question is proving to be difficult for me to grasp. Can anyone help please.

Question

Create a query to display the total number of employees and, of that total,
the number of employees hired in 2005, 2006, 2007 and 2008.

Expected output format

```
Total 2005 2006 2007 2008
107   29   24   19   11
```

The following are my attempts to get the results with separate queries

```
TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY')
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "Total"
FROM employees;

SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "2005"
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') LIKE '2005' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') ;

SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "2006"
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') LIKE '2006' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') ;

SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "2007"
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') LIKE '2007' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') ;

SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "2008"
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') LIKE '2008' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') ;
```

Any help producing the result as one query is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like this should work: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS numEmpls, TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') AS theYear FROM employees GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to *pivot* the data, so you can use your existing query but add a `CASE` expression inside of the aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "Total",
    sum(case when TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') = '2005' then 1 else 0 end) "2005",
    sum(case when TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') = '2006' then 1 else 0 end) "2006",
    sum(case when TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') = '2007' then 1 else 0 end) "2007",
    sum(case when TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') = '2008' then 1 else 0 end) "2008"
FROM employees;
```

Depending on your version of Oracle, you might be able to use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select count(*) over() Total,
    TO_CHAR(hire_date,'YYYY') Year
  from employees
) 
pivot
(
    count(Year)
    for Year in ('2005', '2006', '2007', '2008')
)
```

See [Demo of both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1067/3)

Comment: @knatz You are welcome, I added a version using `PIVOT` if you are using Oracle 11g+

Answer (score 2):

To put these in columns, use conditional aggreagtaion:

```
select count(*) as Total,
       sum(case when to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy') = '2005' then 1 else 0 end) as "2005",
       sum(case when to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy') = '2006' then 1 else 0 end) as "2006",
       sum(case when to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy') = '2007' then 1 else 0 end) as "2007",
       sum(case when to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy') = '2008' then 1 else 0 end) as "2008"
from employees
where to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy') in ('2005', 2006', '2007', '2008')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help is there any advantage to adding the where clause

Comment: To add to what Horus is stating, if the table has data from prior 2005 or after 2008 the count would be off in your first - 'Total' column.

Comment: @Jordan . . . All that is true.  But on re-reading the question, the total is larger than the total for the four years.  Apparently, BlueFeet got it right.  It seems strange to me to have a total in a row that is *not* the total for the four columns, but that is what the question is asking for.